# Update all cells in column to match value of first row?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, field-calculator, attribute-table

I have a point layer; the attribute table includes x and y coordinates of original centroids associated with the points (the points were generated from the perimeters of circle features and still carry centroid data).

Since each layer contains points from two different polygons, individual point in each layer have different centroid values. I need to update the attribute table so that each row has the same value; conveniently, for each layer the desired value is from the first row (i.e. FID=1).

I'm working in ModelBuilder, so ideally this would be a model-friendly solution.

Is there an easy fix that I'm blanking on?

Possibly something in the field calculator?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site James. Do you use Python, or are you committed to ModelBuilder?

Comment: I'm with Aaron. This is a *very* easy python but really not easy in model builder. As a python script you can create a tool and use it in an existing model.. how does that sound to you?

Answer (score 1):

In a model, this is just a combination of Calculate Value and Calculate Field.

[image: Model with Calculate Value and Calculate Field]

Use a bit of Python code/cursors in Calculate Value to pull out the first value from the data source. If your data elements are different in your model, adjust the use of `'%Feature Class%'` and `'%Field Name%'` as appropriate.

[image: Calculate Value]

And then hook that up to Calculate Field. With Calculate Field make sure to right-click on the tool and make the Field Name parameter a variable.
[image: Calculate Field]

**Note: I'm just showing for a single field**